# Non Super User cannot alter stored procedures and functions

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running into an issue granted a user access to alter stored procedures and functions within MySQL 5.7.22-0 running on Ubuntu.

- User has ALL PRIV on the database except GRANT
- User has SELECT PRIV on mysql.proc
- User can DROP and CREATE --> they can not ALTER

Here is the output from SHOW GRANTS

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'userA'@'%'

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'userA'@'%'   
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydatabase`.* TO 'userA'@'...  
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proc` TO 'userA'@'%'
```

Output for SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE on a specifc pro

```
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE mydatabase.spAddEmailListContact

spAddEmailListContact   NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO   

CREATE DEFINER=`userB`@`%` PROCEDURE `spAddEmailListContact`(
        IN `EmailListID` INTEGER(11),
        IN `CustID` INTEGER(11),
        IN `ContactID` INTEGER(11))
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
INSERT INTO 
  emaillistcontacts
(
  EMAILLIST_ID,
  CUST_ID,
  CUSTCNT_ID
) 
VALUES (
  EmailListID,
  CustID,
  ContactID
);
END utf8mb4 utf8mb4_general_ci  latin1_swedish_ci
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Note: A key requirement is to allow SEVERAL developers to edit procedures without requiring them to be super users.  (this is so simple to do in mssql :-/ it surprises me that this is difficult in mysql)

Comment: Did the super user build the procedures and functions? If yes, there might be an issue with sql security.

Comment: Using the admin user to change the definer of the procedures in question to the user you want should solve the problem

Comment: No it is set to a different user (the owner of the database). So in the example above the DEFINER is set to "mydatabase@%"

Comment: Wouldn't changing the definer mean that the proc would execute under that user context?  If so, how do I support multiple users for editing the database?  I cannot set the DEFINE to several users, can I?

Comment: To alter the procedure you usually have to be either admin / super user  or be the user specified in the DEFINER of the stored routine

Comment: no, i don't think you can specify more than one user as Definer. But you can create a user for editing the procedures and functions and set the user as Definer so different people can edit them

Comment: There is no "user" called `mydatabase`??  Check the `DEFINER`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE ...`  (You can leave out the body if necessary for privacy.)

Comment: I have edited the main post with the result of SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this in the `CREATE`:

```
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```

or, more likely,

```
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

Comment: that changes the security to the user that is executing it - this would mean that when the proc is used in the application it would run under a different security context for each result based on the user connecting.  This would be a major change in the design.  What I am struggling with is -- if a user has ALTER PROCEDURE permissions than they should be able to edit a stored proc -- otherwise what is the point of that GRANT?